# How to rotate a part of SVG on itself with CSS?

Tags: css, svg

I want to rotate only a part of an SVG on itself with `transform: rotate()` (and not on the whole SVG). These are the wheels of a bike.

I tried with `transform-origin: 50% 50%` but it doesn't work.

My SVG include in HTML:

```
<svg class="icon icon-bike-anim card-simple__icon" viewBox="0 0 30 32">
  <title>bike-2</title>
  <path fill="#fff" style="fill: var(--color1, #fff)" d="M0 0h30.476v32h-30.476v-32z"></path>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#3a4161" style="stroke: var(--color2, #3a4161)" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.5714" d="M11.213 4.361c0-1.481 0.892-2.706 2.388-2.706 1.481 0 2.388 1.21 2.388 2.706-0.955 0.796-2.388 0.796-2.388 0.796s-1.433 0-2.388-0.796z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M15.704 4.336c0 0 0 0 0.285 0.025s0.285 0.025 0.285 0.025l-0 0.001-0 0.003-0.001 0.009c-0.001 0.008-0.002 0.019-0.003 0.033-0.003 0.029-0.008 0.070-0.014 0.122-0.013 0.104-0.035 0.252-0.067 0.43-0.064 0.353-0.172 0.828-0.349 1.307-0.176 0.476-0.426 0.973-0.783 1.355-0.363 0.388-0.842 0.663-1.455 0.663v-0.571c0.422 0 0.758-0.183 1.038-0.482 0.285-0.304 0.502-0.723 0.665-1.163 0.162-0.437 0.262-0.877 0.323-1.211 0.030-0.166 0.050-0.304 0.062-0.4 0.006-0.048 0.010-0.085 0.013-0.11 0.001-0.013 0.002-0.022 0.003-0.028l0.001-0.007 0-0.002z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M10.928 4.386c0-0 0-0 0.285-0.025s0.285-0.025 0.285-0.025l0 0.002 0.001 0.007c0.001 0.006 0.002 0.015 0.003 0.028 0.003 0.025 0.007 0.062 0.013 0.11 0.012 0.096 0.032 0.234 0.062 0.4 0.060 0.333 0.161 0.774 0.323 1.211 0.162 0.44 0.38 0.858 0.665 1.163 0.279 0.299 0.616 0.482 1.038 0.482v0.571c-0.613 0-1.092-0.275-1.455-0.663-0.357-0.382-0.607-0.879-0.783-1.355-0.177-0.478-0.285-0.954-0.349-1.307-0.032-0.177-0.053-0.325-0.067-0.43-0.007-0.052-0.011-0.094-0.014-0.122-0.002-0.014-0.003-0.026-0.003-0.033l-0.001-0.009-0-0.003-0-0.001z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M13.315 2.291v-0.637h0.571v0.637h-0.571z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M13.315 4.202v-1.433h0.571v1.433h-0.571z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M15.468 2.367l-0.478 1.751-0.551-0.15 0.478-1.751 0.551 0.15z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M12.284 2.216l0.478 1.751-0.551 0.15-0.478-1.751 0.551-0.15z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M8.857 4.839c0-2.625 2.118-4.743 4.743-4.743s4.743 2.118 4.743 4.743c0 2.197-1.503 4.050-3.532 4.581l-0.973 1.468c-0.053 0.080-0.142 0.128-0.238 0.128s-0.185-0.048-0.238-0.128l-0.973-1.468c-2.028-0.531-3.532-2.384-3.532-4.581zM13.601 0.667c-2.31 0-4.172 1.862-4.172 4.172 0 1.966 1.371 3.62 3.203 4.052 0.071 0.017 0.132 0.060 0.173 0.12l0.797 1.201 0.797-1.201c0.040-0.061 0.102-0.104 0.173-0.12 1.832-0.432 3.203-2.086 3.203-4.052 0-2.31-1.862-4.172-4.172-4.172z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M13.51 6.319c0.059-0.020 0.122-0.020 0.181 0l1.433 0.478-0.181 0.542-1.342-0.447-1.342 0.447-0.181-0.542 1.433-0.478z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M17.737 17.372c0.002-0.191 0.158-0.344 0.349-0.343 0.598 0.005 2.164 0.011 3.731 0.016 1.535 0.005 3.071 0.010 3.701 0.016 0.191 0.002 0.344 0.158 0.343 0.349s-0.158 0.344-0.349 0.343c-0.606-0.005-2.147-0.010-3.69-0.016-1.581-0.005-3.163-0.011-3.743-0.016-0.191-0.002-0.344-0.158-0.343-0.349z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M10.546 13.823c0.061-0.13 0.193-0.211 0.336-0.207l6.141 0.163c0.152 0.004 0.285 0.103 0.333 0.248l1.068 3.235c0.063 0.189-0.040 0.393-0.23 0.456s-0.393-0.040-0.456-0.23l-0.989-2.994-5.652-0.15-2.592 5.524c-0.085 0.18-0.3 0.258-0.48 0.173s-0.258-0.3-0.173-0.48l2.692-5.738z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M17.121 13.246c0.076 0.285 0.164 0.612 0.291 0.996 0.062 0.189-0.040 0.393-0.23 0.456s-0.393-0.040-0.456-0.23c-0.134-0.405-0.226-0.751-0.303-1.037-0.011-0.043-0.022-0.084-0.033-0.123-0.086-0.318-0.147-0.521-0.223-0.665-0.065-0.125-0.131-0.184-0.229-0.225-0.119-0.049-0.314-0.080-0.661-0.069-0.199 0.006-0.366-0.15-0.372-0.349s0.15-0.366 0.349-0.372c0.378-0.012 0.696 0.015 0.958 0.123 0.282 0.116 0.465 0.311 0.594 0.557 0.119 0.227 0.199 0.51 0.281 0.813 0.011 0.041 0.022 0.083 0.034 0.126z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M18.391 17.219c0.086 0.17 0.018 0.378-0.152 0.465l-5.412 2.745c-0.17 0.086-0.378 0.018-0.465-0.152s-0.018-0.378 0.152-0.465l5.412-2.745c0.17-0.086 0.378-0.018 0.465 0.152z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M10.724 13.627c0.183-0.055 0.376 0.049 0.43 0.232l1.847 6.162c0.055 0.183-0.049 0.376-0.232 0.43s-0.376-0.049-0.43-0.232l-1.847-6.162c-0.055-0.183 0.049-0.376 0.232-0.43z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M8.212 19.37l4.49 0.406-0.062 0.689-4.49-0.406 0.062-0.689z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M21.005 17.11c0.18-0.063 0.378 0.031 0.441 0.211l1.1 3.127c0.063 0.18-0.031 0.378-0.211 0.441s-0.378-0.031-0.441-0.211l-1.1-3.127c-0.063-0.18 0.031-0.378 0.211-0.441z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M9.408 10.787c0.144-0.064 0.313 0.001 0.377 0.145l1.524 3.429c0.064 0.144-0.001 0.313-0.145 0.377s-0.313-0.001-0.377-0.145l-1.524-3.429c-0.064-0.144 0.001-0.313 0.145-0.377z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M11.338 11.072c-0.001 0.158-0.129 0.285-0.287 0.285l-2.731-0.010c-0.158-0.001-0.285-0.129-0.285-0.287s0.129-0.285 0.287-0.285l2.731 0.010c0.158 0.001 0.285 0.129 0.285 0.287z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M-2.286 17.778h8.381v0.645h-8.381v-0.645z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M0.293 19.39h5.802v0.645h-5.802v-0.645z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M3.839 21.001h2.256v0.645h-2.256v-0.645z"></path>
  <path class="anim-wheel-back" fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M5.631 18.362l2.178 1.258-2.207 1.274c-0.174-0.375-0.272-0.794-0.272-1.236 0-0.465 0.108-0.905 0.3-1.296zM5.822 18.031c0.48-0.721 1.271-1.215 2.178-1.29v2.547l-2.178-1.258zM8.381 19.949l2.288 1.321c-0.497 0.754-1.333 1.263-2.288 1.309v-2.63zM10.857 20.939l-2.286-1.32 2.256-1.303c0.206 0.401 0.323 0.857 0.323 1.341 0 0.46-0.106 0.895-0.293 1.282zM8 22.572c-0.931-0.077-1.738-0.594-2.214-1.345l2.214-1.278v2.623zM8.381 16.735c0.932 0.044 1.75 0.53 2.251 1.254l-2.251 1.3v-2.554zM8.241 16.011c-2.007 0-3.631 1.634-3.631 3.646s1.624 3.646 3.631 3.646c2.007 0 3.631-1.634 3.631-3.646s-1.624-3.646-3.631-3.646z"></path>
  <path class="anim-wheel-front" fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M20.326 19.522l1.489 0.86-1.388 0.801c-0.152-0.279-0.239-0.599-0.239-0.939 0-0.255 0.049-0.499 0.137-0.722zM20.439 19.285c0.305-0.542 0.859-0.924 1.507-0.991v1.861l-1.507-0.87zM22.208 20.609l1.477 0.853c-0.348 0.438-0.879 0.724-1.477 0.742v-1.595zM23.834 21.246l-1.495-0.863 1.605-0.927c0.106 0.241 0.165 0.508 0.165 0.789 0 0.366-0.1 0.708-0.275 1.001zM21.947 22.194c-0.565-0.058-1.059-0.356-1.378-0.79l1.378-0.795v1.585zM22.208 18.285c0.684 0.020 1.28 0.391 1.614 0.938l-1.614 0.932v-1.87zM22.149 17.524c-1.503 0-2.721 1.218-2.721 2.721s1.218 2.721 2.721 2.721c1.503 0 2.721-1.218 2.721-2.721s-1.218-2.721-2.721-2.721z"></path>
</svg>
```

And the SCSS :

```
.icon {
    &-bike-anim,
    &-elephant-anim,
    &-clock-anim {
        width: 74px;
        height: 74px;
      }

    .anim {
        &-wheel-back,
        &-wheel-front,
        &-ball,
        &-hour,
        &-minute {
            transform-origin: 50% 50%;
            animation: turn-wheel 3s linear 1s infinite running;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.icon-bike-anim, .icon-elephant-anim, .icon-clock-anim {
  width: 74px;
  height: 74px;
}
.icon .anim-wheel-back, .icon .anim-wheel-front, .icon .anim-ball, .icon .anim-hour, .icon .anim-minute {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation: turn-wheel 3s linear 1s infinite running;
}
```

```html
<svg class="icon icon-bike-anim card-simple__icon" viewBox="0 0 30 32">
  <title>bike-2</title>
  <path fill="#fff" style="fill: var(--color1, #fff)" d="M0 0h30.476v32h-30.476v-32z"></path>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#3a4161" style="stroke: var(--color2, #3a4161)" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.5714" d="M11.213 4.361c0-1.481 0.892-2.706 2.388-2.706 1.481 0 2.388 1.21 2.388 2.706-0.955 0.796-2.388 0.796-2.388 0.796s-1.433 0-2.388-0.796z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M15.704 4.336c0 0 0 0 0.285 0.025s0.285 0.025 0.285 0.025l-0 0.001-0 0.003-0.001 0.009c-0.001 0.008-0.002 0.019-0.003 0.033-0.003 0.029-0.008 0.070-0.014 0.122-0.013 0.104-0.035 0.252-0.067 0.43-0.064 0.353-0.172 0.828-0.349 1.307-0.176 0.476-0.426 0.973-0.783 1.355-0.363 0.388-0.842 0.663-1.455 0.663v-0.571c0.422 0 0.758-0.183 1.038-0.482 0.285-0.304 0.502-0.723 0.665-1.163 0.162-0.437 0.262-0.877 0.323-1.211 0.030-0.166 0.050-0.304 0.062-0.4 0.006-0.048 0.010-0.085 0.013-0.11 0.001-0.013 0.002-0.022 0.003-0.028l0.001-0.007 0-0.002z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M10.928 4.386c0-0 0-0 0.285-0.025s0.285-0.025 0.285-0.025l0 0.002 0.001 0.007c0.001 0.006 0.002 0.015 0.003 0.028 0.003 0.025 0.007 0.062 0.013 0.11 0.012 0.096 0.032 0.234 0.062 0.4 0.060 0.333 0.161 0.774 0.323 1.211 0.162 0.44 0.38 0.858 0.665 1.163 0.279 0.299 0.616 0.482 1.038 0.482v0.571c-0.613 0-1.092-0.275-1.455-0.663-0.357-0.382-0.607-0.879-0.783-1.355-0.177-0.478-0.285-0.954-0.349-1.307-0.032-0.177-0.053-0.325-0.067-0.43-0.007-0.052-0.011-0.094-0.014-0.122-0.002-0.014-0.003-0.026-0.003-0.033l-0.001-0.009-0-0.003-0-0.001z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M13.315 2.291v-0.637h0.571v0.637h-0.571z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M13.315 4.202v-1.433h0.571v1.433h-0.571z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M15.468 2.367l-0.478 1.751-0.551-0.15 0.478-1.751 0.551 0.15z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M12.284 2.216l0.478 1.751-0.551 0.15-0.478-1.751 0.551-0.15z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M8.857 4.839c0-2.625 2.118-4.743 4.743-4.743s4.743 2.118 4.743 4.743c0 2.197-1.503 4.050-3.532 4.581l-0.973 1.468c-0.053 0.080-0.142 0.128-0.238 0.128s-0.185-0.048-0.238-0.128l-0.973-1.468c-2.028-0.531-3.532-2.384-3.532-4.581zM13.601 0.667c-2.31 0-4.172 1.862-4.172 4.172 0 1.966 1.371 3.62 3.203 4.052 0.071 0.017 0.132 0.060 0.173 0.12l0.797 1.201 0.797-1.201c0.040-0.061 0.102-0.104 0.173-0.12 1.832-0.432 3.203-2.086 3.203-4.052 0-2.31-1.862-4.172-4.172-4.172z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M13.51 6.319c0.059-0.020 0.122-0.020 0.181 0l1.433 0.478-0.181 0.542-1.342-0.447-1.342 0.447-0.181-0.542 1.433-0.478z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M17.737 17.372c0.002-0.191 0.158-0.344 0.349-0.343 0.598 0.005 2.164 0.011 3.731 0.016 1.535 0.005 3.071 0.010 3.701 0.016 0.191 0.002 0.344 0.158 0.343 0.349s-0.158 0.344-0.349 0.343c-0.606-0.005-2.147-0.010-3.69-0.016-1.581-0.005-3.163-0.011-3.743-0.016-0.191-0.002-0.344-0.158-0.343-0.349z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M10.546 13.823c0.061-0.13 0.193-0.211 0.336-0.207l6.141 0.163c0.152 0.004 0.285 0.103 0.333 0.248l1.068 3.235c0.063 0.189-0.040 0.393-0.23 0.456s-0.393-0.040-0.456-0.23l-0.989-2.994-5.652-0.15-2.592 5.524c-0.085 0.18-0.3 0.258-0.48 0.173s-0.258-0.3-0.173-0.48l2.692-5.738z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M17.121 13.246c0.076 0.285 0.164 0.612 0.291 0.996 0.062 0.189-0.040 0.393-0.23 0.456s-0.393-0.040-0.456-0.23c-0.134-0.405-0.226-0.751-0.303-1.037-0.011-0.043-0.022-0.084-0.033-0.123-0.086-0.318-0.147-0.521-0.223-0.665-0.065-0.125-0.131-0.184-0.229-0.225-0.119-0.049-0.314-0.080-0.661-0.069-0.199 0.006-0.366-0.15-0.372-0.349s0.15-0.366 0.349-0.372c0.378-0.012 0.696 0.015 0.958 0.123 0.282 0.116 0.465 0.311 0.594 0.557 0.119 0.227 0.199 0.51 0.281 0.813 0.011 0.041 0.022 0.083 0.034 0.126z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M18.391 17.219c0.086 0.17 0.018 0.378-0.152 0.465l-5.412 2.745c-0.17 0.086-0.378 0.018-0.465-0.152s-0.018-0.378 0.152-0.465l5.412-2.745c0.17-0.086 0.378-0.018 0.465 0.152z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M10.724 13.627c0.183-0.055 0.376 0.049 0.43 0.232l1.847 6.162c0.055 0.183-0.049 0.376-0.232 0.43s-0.376-0.049-0.43-0.232l-1.847-6.162c-0.055-0.183 0.049-0.376 0.232-0.43z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M8.212 19.37l4.49 0.406-0.062 0.689-4.49-0.406 0.062-0.689z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M21.005 17.11c0.18-0.063 0.378 0.031 0.441 0.211l1.1 3.127c0.063 0.18-0.031 0.378-0.211 0.441s-0.378-0.031-0.441-0.211l-1.1-3.127c-0.063-0.18 0.031-0.378 0.211-0.441z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M9.408 10.787c0.144-0.064 0.313 0.001 0.377 0.145l1.524 3.429c0.064 0.144-0.001 0.313-0.145 0.377s-0.313-0.001-0.377-0.145l-1.524-3.429c-0.064-0.144 0.001-0.313 0.145-0.377z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M11.338 11.072c-0.001 0.158-0.129 0.285-0.287 0.285l-2.731-0.010c-0.158-0.001-0.285-0.129-0.285-0.287s0.129-0.285 0.287-0.285l2.731 0.010c0.158 0.001 0.285 0.129 0.285 0.287z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M-2.286 17.778h8.381v0.645h-8.381v-0.645z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M0.293 19.39h5.802v0.645h-5.802v-0.645z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M3.839 21.001h2.256v0.645h-2.256v-0.645z"></path>
  <path class="anim-wheel-back" fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M5.631 18.362l2.178 1.258-2.207 1.274c-0.174-0.375-0.272-0.794-0.272-1.236 0-0.465 0.108-0.905 0.3-1.296zM5.822 18.031c0.48-0.721 1.271-1.215 2.178-1.29v2.547l-2.178-1.258zM8.381 19.949l2.288 1.321c-0.497 0.754-1.333 1.263-2.288 1.309v-2.63zM10.857 20.939l-2.286-1.32 2.256-1.303c0.206 0.401 0.323 0.857 0.323 1.341 0 0.46-0.106 0.895-0.293 1.282zM8 22.572c-0.931-0.077-1.738-0.594-2.214-1.345l2.214-1.278v2.623zM8.381 16.735c0.932 0.044 1.75 0.53 2.251 1.254l-2.251 1.3v-2.554zM8.241 16.011c-2.007 0-3.631 1.634-3.631 3.646s1.624 3.646 3.631 3.646c2.007 0 3.631-1.634 3.631-3.646s-1.624-3.646-3.631-3.646z"></path>
  <path class="anim-wheel-front" fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M20.326 19.522l1.489 0.86-1.388 0.801c-0.152-0.279-0.239-0.599-0.239-0.939 0-0.255 0.049-0.499 0.137-0.722zM20.439 19.285c0.305-0.542 0.859-0.924 1.507-0.991v1.861l-1.507-0.87zM22.208 20.609l1.477 0.853c-0.348 0.438-0.879 0.724-1.477 0.742v-1.595zM23.834 21.246l-1.495-0.863 1.605-0.927c0.106 0.241 0.165 0.508 0.165 0.789 0 0.366-0.1 0.708-0.275 1.001zM21.947 22.194c-0.565-0.058-1.059-0.356-1.378-0.79l1.378-0.795v1.585zM22.208 18.285c0.684 0.020 1.28 0.391 1.614 0.938l-1.614 0.932v-1.87zM22.149 17.524c-1.503 0-2.721 1.218-2.721 2.721s1.218 2.721 2.721 2.721c1.503 0 2.721-1.218 2.721-2.721s-1.218-2.721-2.721-2.721z"></path>
</svg>
```

With this code the wheels rotate in relation to the SVG axis and not on themselves. Can you help me please ?

Original image:

[image]

Image with rotation:

[image]

Comment: `transform-origin: 50% 50%;` relates to the center of the SVG...not the path IIRC.

Comment: I'm assuming your CSS is SCSS (since it compiled sensibly and seemed to work), when you're writing your question it's far easier to help you if you use the correct terminology, and provide code that's easier to turn into a reproducible example, which is why I've compiled the SCSS into CSS in the runnable snippet. Also, please consider - for the ease of copying your code into our answers - using the Snippets feature, if your question is about HTML, JavaScript and/or CSS. :)

Comment: What is the definition of turn-wheel? Is your question missing keyframes?

Comment: Yes, it my keyframe, I forgot it in my example. Thank you all for your quick answers ! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`transform-origin` in SVG refers to the center of the SVG not the sub-element (such as the `path`).

However, you can use CSS to "redefine" how you want the transform applied using `transform-box` to tell that particular element to determine it's own center.

```
 transform-box:fill-box;
```

> The transform-box CSS property defines the **layout box** to which the transform and transform-origin properties relate.
>
> <sup>[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box)</sup>

*Note, still an experimental property*

```css
.icon-bike-anim,
.icon-elephant-anim,
.icon-clock-anim {
  width: 274px;
  height: 274px;
}

.icon .anim-wheel-back,
.icon .anim-wheel-front,
.icon .anim-ball,
.icon .anim-hour,
.icon .anim-minute {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  animation: turn-wheel 3s linear 1s infinite running;
}

@keyframes turn-wheel {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1turn)
  }
  ;
}
```

```html
<svg class="icon icon-bike-anim card-simple__icon" viewBox="0 0 30 32">
  <title>bike-2</title>
  <path fill="#fff" style="fill: var(--color1, #fff)" d="M0 0h30.476v32h-30.476v-32z"></path>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#3a4161" style="stroke: var(--color2, #3a4161)" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.5714" d="M11.213 4.361c0-1.481 0.892-2.706 2.388-2.706 1.481 0 2.388 1.21 2.388 2.706-0.955 0.796-2.388 0.796-2.388 0.796s-1.433 0-2.388-0.796z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M15.704 4.336c0 0 0 0 0.285 0.025s0.285 0.025 0.285 0.025l-0 0.001-0 0.003-0.001 0.009c-0.001 0.008-0.002 0.019-0.003 0.033-0.003 0.029-0.008 0.070-0.014 0.122-0.013 0.104-0.035 0.252-0.067 0.43-0.064 0.353-0.172 0.828-0.349 1.307-0.176 0.476-0.426 0.973-0.783 1.355-0.363 0.388-0.842 0.663-1.455 0.663v-0.571c0.422 0 0.758-0.183 1.038-0.482 0.285-0.304 0.502-0.723 0.665-1.163 0.162-0.437 0.262-0.877 0.323-1.211 0.030-0.166 0.050-0.304 0.062-0.4 0.006-0.048 0.010-0.085 0.013-0.11 0.001-0.013 0.002-0.022 0.003-0.028l0.001-0.007 0-0.002z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M10.928 4.386c0-0 0-0 0.285-0.025s0.285-0.025 0.285-0.025l0 0.002 0.001 0.007c0.001 0.006 0.002 0.015 0.003 0.028 0.003 0.025 0.007 0.062 0.013 0.11 0.012 0.096 0.032 0.234 0.062 0.4 0.060 0.333 0.161 0.774 0.323 1.211 0.162 0.44 0.38 0.858 0.665 1.163 0.279 0.299 0.616 0.482 1.038 0.482v0.571c-0.613 0-1.092-0.275-1.455-0.663-0.357-0.382-0.607-0.879-0.783-1.355-0.177-0.478-0.285-0.954-0.349-1.307-0.032-0.177-0.053-0.325-0.067-0.43-0.007-0.052-0.011-0.094-0.014-0.122-0.002-0.014-0.003-0.026-0.003-0.033l-0.001-0.009-0-0.003-0-0.001z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M13.315 2.291v-0.637h0.571v0.637h-0.571z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M13.315 4.202v-1.433h0.571v1.433h-0.571z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M15.468 2.367l-0.478 1.751-0.551-0.15 0.478-1.751 0.551 0.15z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M12.284 2.216l0.478 1.751-0.551 0.15-0.478-1.751 0.551-0.15z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M8.857 4.839c0-2.625 2.118-4.743 4.743-4.743s4.743 2.118 4.743 4.743c0 2.197-1.503 4.050-3.532 4.581l-0.973 1.468c-0.053 0.080-0.142 0.128-0.238 0.128s-0.185-0.048-0.238-0.128l-0.973-1.468c-2.028-0.531-3.532-2.384-3.532-4.581zM13.601 0.667c-2.31 0-4.172 1.862-4.172 4.172 0 1.966 1.371 3.62 3.203 4.052 0.071 0.017 0.132 0.060 0.173 0.12l0.797 1.201 0.797-1.201c0.040-0.061 0.102-0.104 0.173-0.12 1.832-0.432 3.203-2.086 3.203-4.052 0-2.31-1.862-4.172-4.172-4.172z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M13.51 6.319c0.059-0.020 0.122-0.020 0.181 0l1.433 0.478-0.181 0.542-1.342-0.447-1.342 0.447-0.181-0.542 1.433-0.478z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M17.737 17.372c0.002-0.191 0.158-0.344 0.349-0.343 0.598 0.005 2.164 0.011 3.731 0.016 1.535 0.005 3.071 0.010 3.701 0.016 0.191 0.002 0.344 0.158 0.343 0.349s-0.158 0.344-0.349 0.343c-0.606-0.005-2.147-0.010-3.69-0.016-1.581-0.005-3.163-0.011-3.743-0.016-0.191-0.002-0.344-0.158-0.343-0.349z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M10.546 13.823c0.061-0.13 0.193-0.211 0.336-0.207l6.141 0.163c0.152 0.004 0.285 0.103 0.333 0.248l1.068 3.235c0.063 0.189-0.040 0.393-0.23 0.456s-0.393-0.040-0.456-0.23l-0.989-2.994-5.652-0.15-2.592 5.524c-0.085 0.18-0.3 0.258-0.48 0.173s-0.258-0.3-0.173-0.48l2.692-5.738z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M17.121 13.246c0.076 0.285 0.164 0.612 0.291 0.996 0.062 0.189-0.040 0.393-0.23 0.456s-0.393-0.040-0.456-0.23c-0.134-0.405-0.226-0.751-0.303-1.037-0.011-0.043-0.022-0.084-0.033-0.123-0.086-0.318-0.147-0.521-0.223-0.665-0.065-0.125-0.131-0.184-0.229-0.225-0.119-0.049-0.314-0.080-0.661-0.069-0.199 0.006-0.366-0.15-0.372-0.349s0.15-0.366 0.349-0.372c0.378-0.012 0.696 0.015 0.958 0.123 0.282 0.116 0.465 0.311 0.594 0.557 0.119 0.227 0.199 0.51 0.281 0.813 0.011 0.041 0.022 0.083 0.034 0.126z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M18.391 17.219c0.086 0.17 0.018 0.378-0.152 0.465l-5.412 2.745c-0.17 0.086-0.378 0.018-0.465-0.152s-0.018-0.378 0.152-0.465l5.412-2.745c0.17-0.086 0.378-0.018 0.465 0.152z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M10.724 13.627c0.183-0.055 0.376 0.049 0.43 0.232l1.847 6.162c0.055 0.183-0.049 0.376-0.232 0.43s-0.376-0.049-0.43-0.232l-1.847-6.162c-0.055-0.183 0.049-0.376 0.232-0.43z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M8.212 19.37l4.49 0.406-0.062 0.689-4.49-0.406 0.062-0.689z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M21.005 17.11c0.18-0.063 0.378 0.031 0.441 0.211l1.1 3.127c0.063 0.18-0.031 0.378-0.211 0.441s-0.378-0.031-0.441-0.211l-1.1-3.127c-0.063-0.18 0.031-0.378 0.211-0.441z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M9.408 10.787c0.144-0.064 0.313 0.001 0.377 0.145l1.524 3.429c0.064 0.144-0.001 0.313-0.145 0.377s-0.313-0.001-0.377-0.145l-1.524-3.429c-0.064-0.144 0.001-0.313 0.145-0.377z"></path>
  <path fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M11.338 11.072c-0.001 0.158-0.129 0.285-0.287 0.285l-2.731-0.010c-0.158-0.001-0.285-0.129-0.285-0.287s0.129-0.285 0.287-0.285l2.731 0.010c0.158 0.001 0.285 0.129 0.285 0.287z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M-2.286 17.778h8.381v0.645h-8.381v-0.645z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M0.293 19.39h5.802v0.645h-5.802v-0.645z"></path>
  <path fill="#3a4161" style="fill: var(--color2, #3a4161)" d="M3.839 21.001h2.256v0.645h-2.256v-0.645z"></path>
  <path class="anim-wheel-back" fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M5.631 18.362l2.178 1.258-2.207 1.274c-0.174-0.375-0.272-0.794-0.272-1.236 0-0.465 0.108-0.905 0.3-1.296zM5.822 18.031c0.48-0.721 1.271-1.215 2.178-1.29v2.547l-2.178-1.258zM8.381 19.949l2.288 1.321c-0.497 0.754-1.333 1.263-2.288 1.309v-2.63zM10.857 20.939l-2.286-1.32 2.256-1.303c0.206 0.401 0.323 0.857 0.323 1.341 0 0.46-0.106 0.895-0.293 1.282zM8 22.572c-0.931-0.077-1.738-0.594-2.214-1.345l2.214-1.278v2.623zM8.381 16.735c0.932 0.044 1.75 0.53 2.251 1.254l-2.251 1.3v-2.554zM8.241 16.011c-2.007 0-3.631 1.634-3.631 3.646s1.624 3.646 3.631 3.646c2.007 0 3.631-1.634 3.631-3.646s-1.624-3.646-3.631-3.646z"></path>
  <path class="anim-wheel-front" fill="#e850aa" style="fill: var(--color3, #e850aa)" d="M20.326 19.522l1.489 0.86-1.388 0.801c-0.152-0.279-0.239-0.599-0.239-0.939 0-0.255 0.049-0.499 0.137-0.722zM20.439 19.285c0.305-0.542 0.859-0.924 1.507-0.991v1.861l-1.507-0.87zM22.208 20.609l1.477 0.853c-0.348 0.438-0.879 0.724-1.477 0.742v-1.595zM23.834 21.246l-1.495-0.863 1.605-0.927c0.106 0.241 0.165 0.508 0.165 0.789 0 0.366-0.1 0.708-0.275 1.001zM21.947 22.194c-0.565-0.058-1.059-0.356-1.378-0.79l1.378-0.795v1.585zM22.208 18.285c0.684 0.020 1.28 0.391 1.614 0.938l-1.614 0.932v-1.87zM22.149 17.524c-1.503 0-2.721 1.218-2.721 2.721s1.218 2.721 2.721 2.721c1.503 0 2.721-1.218 2.721-2.721s-1.218-2.721-2.721-2.721z"></path>
</svg>
```